# Start Activity before MainActivity in SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 Activitys

- MainActivity
- LoginActivity

I want verify if user has logged, else show my LoginActivity before the MainActivity apears.

When I put this in OnCreateView of MainActivity I have an error:

```
    if(Login.isLogged()){
        selectItem(0);//starts the fragment
    }
    else {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: MAIN java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo { .....MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Ps: My MainActivity is an SherlockFragmentActivity. I'm using DrawerLayout.

How can i start my LoginActivity before SherlockFragmentActivity?
Thanks

Comment: Put more log error, please. Somethiing is null in your code.

Comment: Manifest correct aswell?

Comment: Yeap. IN your log error is saying that something is null and you are using it. But if you paste more we will be able to see  the line number that it happens

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would put LoginActiviy as launcher activity. There I would check if user has already logged in, if he has start new activity.. Something like this:

```
//in onCreate of LoginActivity

if (hasLogedIn) {
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
} else {
// show him login activity, setContentView etc... 
// save hasLogin boolean as true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make this changes in your AndroidManifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.alphabets.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >

<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

<activity
        android:name="com.example.alphabets.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Login Activity as your default activity. Check Login status. If user is logged in, call Main Activity and finish() the Login Activity. else, wait for user input